# binding via argument name and pattern match in ocaml

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

In OCaml, how can I both :

- pattern match on an argument
- and also bind the unmatched argument to a name ?

in haskell it is like

```
f arg@{..} = some code using both arg and its fields
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `as`. E.g.:

```ml
let f ((a, b) as original) =
  if a > b then
    (b, a)
  else
    original
```

or:

```
let g = function
| [] -> []
| (x :: _) as l -> x :: l
```